# Optimize python file comparison script

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, csv, complexity-theory

I have written a script which works, but I'm guessing isn't the most efficient.  What I need to do is the following:

- Compare two csv files that contain user information. It's essentially a member list where one file is a more updated version of the other.
- The files contain data such as ID, name, status, etc, etc
- Write to a third csv file ONLY the records in the new file that either don't exist in the older file, or contain updated information.  For each record, there is a unique ID that allows me to determine if a record is new or previously existed.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
import csv

fileAin = open('old.csv','rb')
fOld = csv.reader(fileAin)

fileBin = open('new.csv','rb')
fNew = csv.reader(fileBin)

fileCout = open('NewAndUpdated.csv','wb')
fNewUpdate = csv.writer(fileCout)

old = []
new = []

for row in fOld:
    old.append(row)
for row in fNew:
    new.append(row)

output = []

x = len(new)
i = 0
num = 0

while i < x:
    if new[num] not in old:
        fNewUpdate.writerow(new[num])

    num += 1
    i += 1

fileAin.close()
fileBin.close()
fileCout.close()
```

In terms of functionality, this script works.  However I'm trying to run this on files that contain hundreds of thousands of records and it's taking hours to complete.  I am guessing the problem lies with reading both files to lists and treating the entire row of data as a single string for comparison.

My question is, for what I am trying to do is this there a faster, more efficient, way to process the two files to create the third file containing only new and updated records?  I don't really have a target time, just mostly wanting to understand if there are better ways in Python to process these files.

Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE to include sample row of data:

123456789,34,DOE,JOHN,1764756,1234 MAIN ST.,CITY,STATE,305,1,A

Comment: An aside: since you're on 2.7, why not use context managers to open the files? that way they'll get closed even if there's an error without you having to write `try: ... except IOError: ...` http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

Comment: Can you give us an example row of the data?

Comment: That would be because I'm still very new to Python.  I picked it up more out of necessity than anything else for my job.  A lot of what I need to do is fairly simple, just needs to be done many times over.  I'm not familiar with the context managers that you've mentioned, but thank you for providing a link.  I'll check it out and learn some more.  Thank you!

Comment: Sample row of data included in the main posting.

Comment: Is the first value the unique ID?

Comment: Correct, first value is the unique ID.  The rest of the data is information for that record which may or may not be updated from what is in the older version of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?  One of the biggest inefficiencies of your code is checking whether new[num] is in old every time because old is a list so you have to iterate through the entire list.  Using a dictionary is much much faster.

```
import csv

fileAin = open('old.csv','rb')
fOld = csv.reader(fileAin)

fileBin = open('new.csv','rb')
fNew = csv.reader(fileBin)

fileCout = open('NewAndUpdated.csv','wb')
fNewUpdate = csv.writer(fileCout)

old = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in fOld}
new = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in fNew}
fileAin.close()
fileBin.close()

output = {}

for row_id in new:
    if row_id not in old or not old[row_id] == new[row_id]:
        output[row_id] = new[row_id]

for row_id in output:
    fNewUpdate.writerow([row_id] + output[row_id])


fileCout.close()
```

Comment: This certainly processed the files incredibly fast.  However, my expected output file contains the entire New.csv file.  I'll tinker with this script to see if I can get it to just write new or updated records.  Thanks for the headstart.

Comment: Do old and new have the exact same number of columns?  My code makes that assumption.

Comment: Yes, old and new have an identical number of columns.  Using my sample row I would be looking for something like this:  old:  123456789,34,DOE,JOHN,1764756,1234 MAIN ST.,CITY,STATE,305,1,A   new:  123456789,32,DOE,JOHN,1764756,1234 MAIN ST.,CITY,STATE,305,1,A   The only thing that changed is in in second column where the value changed from a 34 to a 32.  In that instance, I need that record copied to the output file, along with any brand new records.

Comment: I think the line `if not all(old_col == new_col for old_col in old[row_id] for new_col in new[row_id])` is wrong; this doesn't compare elements pairwise, it checks the cartesian product.  Probably `if not old[row_id] == new[row_id]:` would suffice.

Comment: Yes I was absolutely wrong.  I changed it to zipping them, but I think you are right that old[row_id] == new[row_id] is even better

Comment: @DSM I've changed the code to reflect your advice, I can't believe I was comparing the values like that lol.

Comment: Yes! Tears... tears of joy.  Thank you NolenRoyalty and DSM for your  feedback and input.  The output file I just got matches the one I ran yesterday that was accurate, but took hours to complete.  This time it took 5 seconds.

Comment: For my personal education, would you mind telling me if my understanding of what you guys did is accurate?  If I'm understanding things, you replaced the lists with dicts containing a Key based on the unique id, and a value that consists of the rest of the row's data.  Then you compared the new dict against the old, and keys that are new or keys that aren't new but don't have a value that matches, write to the output file.  Am I understanding the logic behind it all correctly?  If so, is it because you are indexing against just the Keys that makes it so much faster?  Thanks again for your help

Comment: You are absolutely right.  What makes it so much faster is the difference between using in for a list and for a dictionary.  For a list, python must look at every single value in the list and compare it to the value you are looking for.  In a dictionary, because it is a hash table, you only do one lookup.  So the number of checks with N ids is going to increase as N increases when using a list, whereas the number of checks will always be 1 when using a dictionary.

Comment: Testing membership in sets and dicts is very fast: they use hashes (which is why members in sets and keys in dicts need to be hashable).  To find out if something is in the dict, you check the index and then look on the page.  (Very roughly.)  By contrast, to test membership in a list like you were doing, you have to read through the elements one by one.  For nonexistent elements you won't know they're not there until you've read through them all.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks again.  I really appreciate your help.  This is also going to help me optimize a handful of other scripts that I have written.

Comment: BTW: one possible improvement would be to use `for row_id in sorted(output,key=int):` for the last loop [assuming the keys are strings describing integers].  dicts don't have an order, but if you iterate through a sorted list of keys the output will at least be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

difflib is quite efficient: http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data by your unique field(s), and then use a comparison process analogous to the merge step of merge sort:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort