# Python : Compare CSV files and save the difference with first row(Column Names)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have two CSV files as shown below:

**File 1**: `June_01_2018.csv`

[image]

**File 2**: `June_02_2018.csv`

[image]

**Note**: I want to find the difference between these two file and store it into the third file **with the column headers**.

**My try**:

```
with open('June_01_2018.csv', 'r') as f1:
    file1 = f1.readlines()

with open('June_02_2018.csv', 'r') as f2:
    file2 = f2.readlines()

with open('June_Updates.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in file2:
        if line not in file1:
            outFile.write(line)
```

But unable to store the column headers into the third file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
    with open('June_01_2018.csv', 'r') as f1:
        file1 = f1.readlines()

    with open('June_02_2018.csv', 'r') as f2:
        file2 = f2.readlines()

    with open('June_Updates.csv', 'w') as outFile:
        outFile.write(file1[0])
        for line in file2:
            if line not in file1:
                outFile.write(line)
```

Comment: Is the same approach is fine for huge data(around 100 Million) in terms of performance?

Comment: @MAK try this approach if you have big data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932278/optimize-python-file-comparison-script

Comment: You could run out of memory. A different approach would be loading the dataset into a relational database and using SQL to ask for the same. It depends on how often the dataset changes and how often do you need to generate the outFile